# Is there a multithreaded TCP server socket in .NET?

Tags: .net, tcp, parallel-processing, .net-4.5

Say we have 1k clients on one socket one port and we want to reply to some N of them in parallel (meaning have N threads writting to socket in parallel with out mutex that would also mean send packets in parallel) is such thing possible in .net?

Comment: Yes, it is. Look at the Async methods of the `Socket` class.

Comment: I am under the impression that socket sends are serialized at the low-level socket level but it is not clear (to me) if that is also the case at the .NET Socket class level. A true parallel send does not seem to make sense as the receiving end would not know what was what.

Answer (score 0):

You could create all of this yourself using the async socket namespace ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.sockets.aspx)) available in .net. If you would rather use a library to save time then checkout [lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) or [networkcomms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net).

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers for networkcomms.Net*